# using mget function to create a list of dataframes

Tags: r, string, list, dataframe

I have several dataframes that I want to put in a list, so that they will be kept as separate dataframes (i.e. a list **with 6 elements**).
when I do it like this, it works:

```
df.list.fin <- list(data53,data54,data113,data117,data123,data127)
```

I want to make it automatic so I will not have to enter the numbers each time. I tried to do the following:

```
df.list.fin <- list(mget(paste0("data",video_number)))
```

Now I still get a list, but the dataframes within the list are not separable from one another. That is, I get one big list with one element.

Any idea how to correct this?

Comment: You don't need the `list`. Try `df.list.fin <- mget(paste0("data",video_number))`

Comment: here is a possible code for your task: `list_of_df <- Filter(function(x) is(x, "data.frame"), mget(ls()))`

Comment: It worked! that you so much!